# Wordpress Accesspress Parallax Theme: Custom Header don't work like the Live Demo

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

i try to understand why my header don't work like the live demo.

The javascript which create the smooth transistion seems not working with my header..

My one page navigation jumps to far and without the smooth transition :/

The live demo: [Live Demo Accesspress Parallax](http://accesspressthemes.com/theme-demos/?theme=accesspress-parallax)

Anybody know how i can fix it ?

My header(transition jumps to the section without the smooth transition and jumps to far)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you installed the theme correctly? You might have missed something.
I would recommend to check the console to see what Java Script error you are getting.
[image]

Comment: hi,

i have found a solution :), you're right, i have change the code from the demo.php instead of create the parallax section in the theme option.